# devise forgot password email not received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am facing issue with devise forgot password.I am not receiving any email though devise displays messsage that "you will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password in a few minutes".

Ruby-1.9.3 Rails 3.2 devise 2.2.4

My environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"


ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:authentication => :plain,
:domain => 'xyz@gmail.com',
:user_name => 'xyz@gmail.com',
:password => 'abcde',
 }
```

My environment.rb
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

My intializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = "xyz@gmail.com"
```

And development.log shows

```
Sent mail to xyz@gmail.com (3205ms)
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 23:33:01 +1000
From: xyz@gmail.com
Reply-To: x@gyzmail.com
To: xyz@gmail.com
Message-ID: <51caed8dd99a5_15365823b9268927@nbnco-U01.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello xyz@gmail.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this the    link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password     /edit?reset_password_token=zb1mZUEzxpymqE8qorDJ">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 3423ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: This issue is closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422316/rails-app-on-heroku-sending-email-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422316/rails-app-on-heroku-sending-email-error

This issue is closely related to this and fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As have been mentioned above in development mode mails aren't being send for real, if you're curious how that's obtained (and maybe want to override that behavior) look into the following file
config/environments/development.rb:

```
  #don't send emails in development
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Of course it would be better to use some mailtrap but if you want to just quickly see mail in your mailbox just change that false to true and here it goes if you've got properly configured mailer of course.

Edit:

That's my config for gmail and it works, there is no domain param so probably it's making trouble:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :user_name            => '<login>',
      :password             => '<password>',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Edit2: And don't forget to restart your server ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have set the raise_delivery_errors flag to true and I am able to see this error: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::PasswordsController#create 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Comment: I have tested these settings and it works without domain (or with `gmail.com` but not with `example.com`, at least unless you have server in that domain ;)), so remove that line and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks heaps zrl3dx for your reply.I verified my settings against what you gave me and removed the domain from there.tried again and again.I finally stumbled upon the issue by visiting this url and changing the user name and password in setup_mail.rb

Answer (score 0):

In development with your configuration emails are not sent but are just visible in the logs. You can try and use a service such as:

- http://mailtrap.io/pages/ruby_landing
- https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener
- https://github.com/37signals/mail_view

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have set the raise_delivery_errors flag to true and I am able to see this error: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::PasswordsController#create 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted